# Where is $this->baseurl defined in joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, php, configuration

I asked this question on stackoverflow.com first (question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450703/where-is-this-baseurl-defined-in-joomla)). In the comments you can read that it would be better if I ask that question here.

On my joomla website I'm using `echo $this->baseurl;` but it returns the url containing "/index.php". I want to change this to remove "/index.php" from baseurl. But I cannot find the definition line of `$this->baseurl;`.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137080/change-value-of-baseurl-in-joomla) but this is based on the template of the question owner and in my template there isn't something like this.

Suggestions very appreciated :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`$this->baseurl;` is basically the shortcut for `JUri::base()`. It gets the URL you have specified as the `live_site` variable in your *configuration.php* file. If this has no value, then it will use some PHP magic based on a few variables.

So, lets run a few tests. Please report the results back:

#### Test 1:

```
<?php
  echo 'Rule 1: ' . JUri::base() . '\n';
  echo 'Rule 2: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '\n';
  echo 'Rule 3: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '\n';
  echo 'Rule 4: ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '\n';
?>
```

---

#### Test 2:

```
<?php
    echo JUri::base();
    echo JUri::base(true);
?>
```

---

#### Test 3:

In the Global Configuration (Joomla backend), try setting **URL rewriting** to **Yes**.
If this does not work then read Steps **1**, **2** and **5** of the [Apache section on this page](http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs#Apache), and try again.

---

#### Test 4:

At the top of your template's *index.php* file, add the following

```
<?php
    $this->baseurl = JUri::base();
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I changed the `live_site` variable in the configuration.php file to my url (nothing changed). Here are the results: **Rule 1:** http://my-url.com/ **Rule 2:** /index.php **Rule 3:** / **Rule 4:** /index.php

Comment: @Therk - ok, and in your Global Configuration, do you have **URL rewriting** turned on of off?

Comment: @Therk - see test 2 in my answer

Comment: you mean mod_rewrite? This is turned off in Joomla configuration.

Comment: Test 2: `echo JUri::base()` returns "http://myurl.com" and `echo JUri::base(true)` returns nothing

Comment: @Therk - see Test 3 and 4

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day :) Turning mod_rewrite on helped. The index.php isn't linked in `$this->baseurl` anymore. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: why nothing change on my bse url when i edit live_site? thank you

Answer (score 8):

The `$this->baseurl;` is a shortcut to be used from inside a template, instead of calling the `JURI:base();` method, of the JURI class. It is part of the core and you can find it at `/libraries/joomla/environment/uri.php (~line 218).`

If you look at the method, you will see that it checks in the configuration file to see if  the `$live_url` variable is defined. If yes it will return this URL, otherwise it will go through a number of other checks and return your actual base URI.

Most probably you have the **live_url** variable defined in your **`configuration.php`** that includes the **`index.php`** at the end. Check there...

Another possibility is that your current template /template system has somewhere defined the **`$this->baseurl`** property. You can easily override the `$this->baseurl` inside your template by re-defining it again at the top of the `index.php` file of your template, like: `$this->baseurl = JURI::base();`

***Update:**

- I mentioned where you can find the method, but this does not mean that you should go there and do any modifications to the core. That was only for informational purposes.

**Update 2 - for future references**

To complete the information given in this post, the `JURI::base($pathonly boolean)` takes one argument, the `$pathonly` which is a **boolean data type** - `false` is the default.

With `$pathonly = true`, it will return only the path to the site.

**Examples:**

```
<?php echo JURI::base(); ?> Would echo something like: http:://localhost/joomla25/
<?php echo JURI::base(true); ?> Would echo: /joomla25
```

Note that when **$pathonly = true**, the trailing slash at the end of the URI path is ommited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found the method. Should I avoid to change anything there? In the configuration.php file I defined the variable `live_site` as my url and nothing more (I didn't add index.php somewhere).

Comment: Yes nothing to change in the core. The only exception is if someone else has already done something there previously... which has caused the function to work this way. Do you really need to define the live_url variable in your config? Usually is not needed.

Comment: Okay :) It doesn't matter if I define live_url variable. It doesn't change anything... The index.php is always coming up. I could fix the problem using code but this would be very hacky and extremely ugly and I don't want to do this. So I want to modify baseurl that the index.php isn't in it.

Comment: An alternate and quick way is to define your custom baseurl variable inside your template and use this. $mybaseurl = JURI:base(true); echo $mybaseurl;

Comment: And one more thing you could check is if changing your template has any effect on the $this->baseurl.